# How to find the center of a expanding expander

Tags: c#, wpf, expander

OK this has me puzzled and it should be simple

I have this code

```
private void Expander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var expand = e.OriginalSource as Expander;
    if (expand != null)
    {
        var layer = sender as LayerBase;
        var middle = expand.TranslatePoint(new Point(), layer) + new Vector(expand.ActualWidth/2,expand.ActualHeight/2);
        Location.Centre = layer.ScreenToGeoPoint(middle);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

This is what the code is supposed to do,

- Locate the Screen point in the centre of the control
- locate the Geographic point that relates to that screen point
- recentre the map to those coordinates

this is so as to ensure the expander is in the centre of the displayed map, with out moving the expander relative to the map (ie so the top left corner is still in the correct geographic location)

the code itself is functioning however, ActualHeight and ActualWidth are returning the size of the collapsed expander, which is throwing off the centre point by a large margin, I'm assuming that this because the Expanded event is firing before the control redraws. so how do I capture that expanded has changed after the visual tree redraws?

Comment: Your Expander gets centered in pre-expanded state, but you want it centered in fully expanded state ?

Comment: Yes that what I'm trying to achieve, I'm sure its something simple i just can't find it

Comment: Use ScaleTransform

Comment: I hand't considered that but wouldn't that move the expander not the map? The expander is displaying information about a feature on a map, so i need to move the centre point of the map not the expander otherwise the expander will be in the wrong place

Comment: I thought you want to move Expander. So, apply transformation to your map. This should be easy if your map is a WPF control or inside a UserControl.

Comment: the map is DevExpress map control https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/wpf/Map/, not a static image so if I move the control it will move the control not the map

Comment: I've edited the wording see if that helps clarify what i meant

Comment: try add `expand.UpdateLayout();` before `expand.TranslatePoint`- this will update expander layout immediately

Comment: Thanks for the help @cdmnk unfortunately didn't work, size is still 23,27, with a content size of 0,0 where as on the Collapsed event the size is, 400,200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private async void Expander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var expand = e.OriginalSource as Expander;
    if (expand != null)
    {
        var layer = sender as LayerBase;
        // magic
        await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync( ( ) => { } );
        expand.UpdateLayout();
        var middle = expand.TranslatePoint(new Point(), layer) + new Vector(expand.ActualWidth/2,expand.ActualHeight/2);
        Location.Centre = layer.ScreenToGeoPoint(middle);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

This works :)

Comment: That was an inspired idea, i was just messing with a delayed task that was along a similar idea

Comment: Yeah, there's many solutions for doing that, it's WPF way to do Application.DoEvents() from WinForms