# WPF ToolBarPanel width not changed

Tags: wpf

I have a Canvas and a ToolBarPanel inside it.

I want to resize the ToolBarPanel using a Thumb, so I placed the Thumb inside the ToolBarPanel. When I catch the DragDelta of the Thumb, the width is not changed. Below is the code:

```
<Canvas x:Uid="userControlCanvas" Name="userControlCanvas" Width="300" Height="300">
    <ToolBarPanel x:Uid="categoriesToolBar" Name="categoriesToolBar" Visibility="Visible" 
                  Height="300" Width="10" Panel.ZIndex="100" 
                  Background="#CCDCDCDC" 
                  SizeChanged="toolbarSizeChanged">
            <Thumb x:Name="splitPane" Cursor="SizeWE" Height="300" Canvas.Left="2" Width="8" DragStarted="splitPaneDragStarted" DragDelta="splitPaneDragging">
            </Thumb>
    </ToolBarPanel>
</Canvas>
```

And the cs code:

```
    private void splitPaneDragging(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e) {
        categoriesToolBar.Width = categoriesToolBar.ActualWidth + e.HorizontalChange;
        //categoriesToolBar.InvalidateMeasure();
        categoriesToolBar.UpdateLayout();
        //categoriesToolBar.InvalidateArrange();
        //categoriesToolBar.InvalidateVisual();
        //categoriesToolBar.InvalidateMeasure();

        //Width is always the initial width (150)
        Console.WriteLine("ch=" + e.HorizontalChange + " tw=" + categoriesToolBar.Width + " aw=" + categoriesToolBar.ActualWidth);
    }

    private void toolbarSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) {
        // this is not fired when I try to change the width in splitPaneDragging method
    }
```

Comment: Ive had a simalar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187740/how-to-find-the-center-of-a-expanding-expander if its the same issue you need to let the form stabilise before grabbing the size

Comment: Thanks @MikeT, but unfortunately this didn't work for me...